# Debugging a simple JavaScript code

Tags: javascript

Started learning Javascript and I wrote something like this in FireBug of FireFox:

```
var myObject = {
"first_name" : "Rick",
"last_name" : "Hummer"
};

var name;
for (name in myObject) {
if(typeof myObject[name] != 'function') {
  (name + ' : ' + myObject[name])
}

}
```

When I run it, it only shows the last name,  shouldn't it also list first name ?

Plus how can I put break points and debug this anyway?

[image]

Comment: Ypu can add breakpoints and see each line of execution http://getfirebug.com/javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't tell the browser to output the values.

By default it writes out the result of the last executed line which is `(name + ' : ' + myObject[name])`

To solve this simply add `console.log`:

```
var myObject = {
"first_name" : "Rick",
"last_name" : "Hummer"
};

var name;
for (name in myObject) {
  if(typeof myObject[name] != 'function') {
    console.log(name + ' : ' + myObject[name]);
  }
}
```

Works for Firefox 19:
[image: Demo]

Comment: ah I see... console.log ... BUT it is very weird, now it does not even show anything.. Try it yourself :)

Comment: It works for me (FF 19.0.2) - see the screenshot in my answer

Comment: Yes sorry, I should have moved back to the "ALL" tab in FireFox, I was in Errors tab

Answer (score 3):

You have a statement that doesn't do anything, it builds a string but doesn't use it. The debugger is probably just showing you the last statement that was executed.

Change

```
(name + ' : ' + myObject[name])
```

To:

```
console.log(name + ' : ' + myObject[name])
```

and you should see both keys appear in the log.

Answer (score 1):

Also, for debugging, you should simply write 'debugger' (without any quotes) at the line you want to put a breakpoint. As I know all browsers support that statement.